# Ask user to save data before leave the component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a component parent `app-sidebar` that can have two different child depends on variable:

```
<app-content-right *ngIf="!componentService.getEditor.inView"></app-content-right>
        <!-- alternative editors -->
<app-labtech-home *ngIf="componentService.getComponentEditor && componentService.getEditor.inView"></app-labtech-home>
```

I need to inform user with a modal when leave `app-labtech-home` to ask him to leave or not the page without saving. I catch the event with

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log("clicked inside")
    } else {
      if(window.confirm("Are you sure?"))
     alert('Your action here');
    }
  }
```

inside `app-labtech-home` component but it exit without the modal, i need to intercept the exit and do it only if user accept. How can I achieve that? Thanks
**PS**: the route doesn't change, it is a different component in the same page (really a different project)

My routing module:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],canDeactivate:[BackButtonDeactiveGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes

Comment: the route does't change, it is only a different component in the same page

Comment: sorry, I don't read sucesfully your question :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for this:
[link](https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-applications/candeactivate)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

- Create **DeactivateGuardService**

.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class DeactivateGuardService implements  CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>{

  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

- Add **canDeactivate** property in each component route

routing.module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { 
        path: 'example', 
        canDeactivate: [DeactivateGuardService],
        component: ExampleComponent 
      }
    ])
  ]
```

- Call the service method when ever user tries to leave the page having form dirty

.component

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    loading: boolean = false;
     @ViewChild('exampleForm') exampleForm: NgForm;

     canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

        if (this.exampleForm.dirty) {

           alert('Discard Unsaved Changes?');
       }
       return true;
     }     

}
```

Comment: It is the same route with different component

Comment: Show your routing module.

Comment: Here you don't  have same route with different component

Comment: I expressed myself male, I have only one route because I have on the right of the page the container of all the component clickable on the left menu